# d3. change color of nodes individual depending on array content

Tags: javascript, colors, d3.js, geometry

Im working with `d3` since a few days. I chose the [collapse tree](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) to show a layer structure of another project. The `d3` functions in this example are exactly mine. Only changes i did that i ask for the nodes in my project to show them in a tree instead of using `flare.json`.

So i asked for the status ( if its enabled or not). See the code below. If a Layer is enabled the circle for the node shall be green. If its not enabled the circle of the node should be red. The status is given to an array.

```
var statusarray = [];
for (i = 0; i < operational.children.length; i++ ) {

    //var status to save children enabled-status at [i]
    var status = operational.children[i].get("enabled");

    //test output for operational.children at [i]
    console.log(operational.children[i].id + " steht auf " + status) ;

    //Create Array (statusarray) for status with length of operational children (saves true and false)
    statusarray[i] = status;
}
```

The array is build like that: `[true, true, true, false, true , false ....]`

With that data i want to manipulate the circles which fit for the attributes.

EDIT:

My data in the java-script is saved here:

```
  var myjson = {
                    "name": main.id,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": glasspane.id,
                            "children": [
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            // get id of operational layer
                            "name": operational.id,
                            "children": [
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": base.id,
                            "children": [
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                };
```

i begin to fill it with:

```
 for (i = 0 ; i < main.children.length; i++) {
                 // Array for children from root
                   var layer = main.children;
                 // Create childrn from Layers in Arrays and fill myjson with them
                   d_array.forEach(layer[i].children, function (ArrayElement) {
                       myjson.children[i].children.push({"name": ArrayElement.id});
                   }, this);
                  }
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need the additional array, you can simply do

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.enabled ? "green" : "red";
});
```

Edit: If you do need an additional array, you can use the index to cross-reference.

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return statusarray[i] ? "green" : "red";
});
```

Comment: the problem i see. I use a var myson for the treedata. There is no entry for enabled. I can only the get the enabled status in the other project.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the answer to use another array with the same ordering as the nodes.

Comment: not completley working but you helped me more than just copy and paste it. i think i begin to understand. I will play around with that and post my solution. thanks

Comment: ok my new problem is that the array is used for all my nodes. so if i have 10 nodes open in the diagram i get other colours as if i have  20 nodes open and so on.

Comment: so how can i do this for the whole tree?

Comment: Are you updating your tree dynamically? This code should be run when appending new nodes, with the assumption that this will happen only once.

Comment: i think the problem is that is that my array only contains a few nodes. operaitonal isnt even the root.node. I chose it just for testing.

Comment: Ok, could you please clarify what data you have and in exactly what format then? In particular how you would, for a given node, determine whether it's enabled or not.

Comment: How do you determine, for a given datum or node, whether it's enabled?